# How to handle duplicate facebook pixel in nuxtjs by nuxt-facebook-pixel-module

Tags: facebook, nuxt.js, facebook-pixel, facebook-pixel-helper

Hey I wanna track my events from browser and server. I need to configure a nuxt-facebook-pixel-module to do that. Now I only track events from browser. I couldn't find anything about how to do that with this nuxtjs module.

I have two events on my website. The first one is after someone submit form and another is after someone show page.
[image: There is code when someone submit form]

[image: There is something I want to achieve in facebook panel]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to track from server actually, since this is a client-side solution, but I might be wrong.

I'm trying to set it up too tho and I'm having a hard time with it, could you share your solution?

Comment: The problem is that I don't have any solution for now ):